# Правильно ли стоят запятые до и после слова "поэтому"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Все должно быть по правилам, поэтому, когда закончишь, возвращайся ко мне.

Правильно ли стоят две запятые: до и после слова *поэтому*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1) Все должно быть по правилам, (2) поэтому, (3)когда закончишь, возвращайся ко мне.**

Знаки препинания расставлены верно. Это сложное предложение с бессоюзной и союзной подчинительной связью.

Между предложениям 1 и 2 связь **бессоюзная,** наречие ***поэтому*** относится к предложению 2, является в нем  структурным элементом со значением **следствия**.

Придаточное предложение (3) находится внутри главного предложения (2)

Comment: большое спасибо